# Terminated due to memory issue - ViewControllers taking up memory

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm developing a game using sprite kit and have various view controllers for different scenes. Like story mode, multiplayer etc...

I've noticed a problem where every time I open up a view controller with a SpriteKit scene, the memory usage for my app increases. And when the view is dismissed, that memory isn't allocated back?

Is there something I need to be doing in my code to return the memory the ViewController or SpriteKit scene used up upon loading?

EDIT: As requested, here is some code from when the VC loads up with a SpriteKit scene & the code used to dismiss the VC:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene.sks") {
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            view.presentScene(scene)
            (scene as! GameScene).parentVC = self
        }
    }

}
```

For the view dismissal, I first present a loading screen over the UIApplication.shared.keyWindow and then dismiss:

```
        dismiss(animated: true) {
        LoadingScreen?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

The loading screen class is handled in the AppDelegate.

Comment: It would help to see some of the code, that would allow people to see where there might be mistakes or opportunities for optimisation

Comment: Well that's the thing I've got a lot of code. Specifically a whole game, so hence I thought I'd ask the question first and then I could share specific code for specific parts based on what people want to see. And quite frankly, I have no idea which part is contributing, so hopefully someone can point me towards what needs to be looked at.

Comment: Well you say it happens when you load up a view controller. So show that code, and also the code that is dismissing it. Perhaps even provide a pic of a high level structure of how your viewcontrollers are all linked together

Comment: Okay thanks, I've added in that code. I'm not sure what a high level structure is, do you mean just like an image that is like a tree showing their connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's an issue of retain cycles

```
1  if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
2   if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene.sks") {
3      scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
4     view.presentScene(scene)
5    (scene as! GameScene).parentVC = self
    }
}
```

if line 5, inside the closure, you're referencing self, so when the viewcontroller should be deallocated, the reference on line 5 is stopping the deallocation, Can you try this :

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {  
    if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene.sks") {
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        view.presentScene(scene)
        guard  let scene = scene as? GameScene else { return }
        guard let scencePVC = scene.parentVC else { return }
        scencePVC = self 
    }
}
```

I'm trying to fix the issue without knowing the object hierarchy but it's hard. Basically the issue is that you have 2 objects( viewcontrollers) referencing each other that would stop the deallocation.

You can read more about this issue [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) & [here](https://medium.com/mackmobile/avoiding-retain-cycles-in-swift-7b08d50fe3ef)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm a little bit new with swift, I'm getting a bug when I try your suggestion "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'" there's something wrong with the formatting?

Comment: Hi, thanks for editing, but you've said let pvc = parentVC which isn't a class on the View Controller, and then you've got: scene as GameScene has no member of pvc ?

Comment: Hi, I can see you've edited it again but I had to change the guard let scenePVC to a var as a value can't be assigned to a let. And then after that the scenePVC = self delivered a warning: Variable 'scencePVC' was written to, but never read